# setup.py install for dlib: finished with status 'error'

Tags: python, face-recognition, dlib

I'm having problems installing [Adam Geitgey's face_recognition library](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition) on my Windows PC.

I followed [this tutorial for installing `dlib` with Python bindings on windows](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/issues/175) and I've successfully installed the requirements listed there.

However, trying to install `dlib` with pip throws the error

```sh
setup.py install for dlib: finished with status 'error'
```

How can I go about resolving this?

Comment: Please paste in the full log from the installation – "finished with status 'error'" does not aid in debugging.

Comment: What version of Python are you working with? Last time I hit this error, it was because I was working with Python 3.8, and dlib didn't have wheels for that version of Python at the time. And, like @AKX mentioned, a full log from the installation will be helpful.

Comment: @AKX I don't have my computer right now im typing on my phone,but I'll paste the error when I have my computer.

Comment: @monism I use latest python 3. I think python 38. I'm really new to python. Can you help me with how you make it work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for dlib (with its Python bindings) to work well for you on Windows, you need to use a Python installation whose version is 3.6 or lower.

I understand you're using the latest version of Python. If I'm correct in my assumption that you're working with Python 3.8, then you'll have to follow these steps:

- Install Python 3.6 on your PC — take note of the installation path as you'll need this for creating the appropriate virtual environment.
- Create a Python 3.6 virtual environment — this will serve to isolate the dependencies of your current project.
  Assuming your Python 3.6 was installed to `C:\Users\Mfonism\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36` (like it was on my PC :)), you'll create your virtual environment *thusly* (from your project directory):

  ```
  c:\> C:\Users\Mfonism\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe -m venv env36
  ```

  - **venv** is the Python virtual environment module.
  - **env36** is the name of the virtual environment you're creating.
- Activate the so-created virtual environment.

  ```
  c:\>  env36\Scripts\activate
  ```

  The name of the virtual environment (env36) should now appear in the terminal.

---

#### UPDATE: IGNORE THIS BLOCK

- Install your project dependencies with pip.

  ```
  pip install face_recognition
  ```

  If this fails, use the `--no-cache-dir` option to circumvent cached versions of the dependencies.

  ```
  pip install face_recognition --no-cache-dir
  ```

---

#### UPDATE: DO THIS INSTEAD

You will need to install specific versions of `dlib` and `face_recognition`. And you will need to install `dlib` first, or `face_recognition` will try to install the latest version of it, and this will fail.

So:

- Install `dlib 19.8.1`

  ```
  pip install dlib==19.8.1
  ```
- Then install `face_recognition 1.2.2`

  ```
  pip install face_recognition==1.2.2
  ```

Comment: So, I've walked through my previous answer on my PC (in the same environment) and it failed. And I've been able to identify the issue. I've updated the answer to include the steps for successfully solving the problem.